# Cannot POST / login.html

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

I'm having trouble sending data to the server using a form. I already made a register form that works just fine, and for the most part my client side javascript for the login form is very similar to the javascript for the register form, and I just can't figure out why it won't work. It just gives me "Cannot POST /login.html"

Here's the login form html:

```
  <div class="loginTitle">
  <h1>Login</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="loginFormLayout">
    <form method=post id="loginForm">

      <div class="loginFormText">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
      </div>

      <div class="loginFormEntry">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="loginUsername" required>
      </div>

      <div class="loginFormText">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
      </div>

      <div class="loginFormEntry">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name=loginPassword required>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="loginButton">Log In</button>

    </form>
  </div>
```

And here's the client side javascript:

```
//Login as an existing user
const login = document.getElementsByClassName('loginButton');
const loginForm = document.getElementById('loginForm');
const loginURL = 'http://localhost:3000/loginUser';

loginForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData(loginForm);
  let username = formData.get('loginUsername');
  let password = formData.get('loginPassword');
  loginForm.reset();

  let user = { //Create a user object that will be sent to the backend and compared to the user database
    username,
    password
  };

  fetch(loginURL, { //Send the user object to the backend in JSON format to be checked against the database
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(user),
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    }

})});
```

And the server side javascript for now, console logs are just to see if the info is getting up to the server

```
app.post('/loginUser', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.username);
  console.log(req.body.password);
});
```

EDIT: I've also decided to post the info for my register form, which DOES work and uses similar logic to the login form. Maybe I'm missing something that isn't in the login logic

Register form html:

```
<div class="loginMenu">

  <div class="loginTitle">
  <h1>Register</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="registerWarning"></div>

  <div class="loginFormLayout">
    <form method="post" id="registerForm">

      <div class="loginFormText">
        <label for="username" id="newUsername">Username</label>
      </div>

      <div class="loginFormEntry">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Create Username" name="username" required>
      </div>

      <div class="loginFormText">
        <label for="password" id="newPassword">Password</label>
      </div>

      <div class="loginFormEntry">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Create Password" name=password required>
      </div>

      <div class="loginFormText">
        <label for="confirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
      </div>

      <div class="loginFormEntry">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="confirmPassword" required>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="registerButton">Register</button>

    </form>
  </div>

</div>
```

Register form client side javascript:

```
//Register a new user
const register = document.getElementsByClassName('registerButton');
const registerForm = document.getElementById('registerForm');
const registerURL = 'http://localhost:3000/createNewUser';
//When the user presses the register button, get the info from the form
registerForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData(registerForm);
  let newUsername = formData.get('username');
  let newPassword = formData.get('password');
  let confirmPassword = formData.get('confirmPassword')
  registerForm.reset();

  //Make sure new password and confirm password are equal
  if (newPassword == confirmPassword) {
    if (newUsername != "" && newPassword != ""){ //Make sure user enters something for both fields
      
      let newUser = { //Create an object to send to the back end
        newUsername,
        newPassword
      };

      fetch(registerURL, { //Send the newUser object to the backend in JSON format to be added to the database
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(newUser),
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json'
        }
      });

    }
  }
  else { //If newPassword and confirmPassword are not equal, ask the user to enter them correctly
    const registerWarning = document.getElementById('registerWarning');
    registerWarning.innerText = 'Password and Confirm Password do not match';
    registerWarning.style.padding = "10px";
    registerWarning.style.background = 'red';
  };

});
```

Register form server-side javascript:

```
 app.post('/createNewUser', (req, res) => {
      let newUsername = req.body.newUsername;
      let newPassword = req.body.newPassword;
    
      let newUserData = 'INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)';//Use the question marks as placeholders
    
      //Use bcrypt to hash the password before putting it in the database
      bcrypt.hash(newPassword, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
        db.query(newUserData, [newUsername, hash], function(err, result) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log('New user registered');
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: It would be helpful to explain what "it doesn't work" looks like.

Comment: It's the title of the post, when I hit the submit button, it says Cannot POST /login.html

Comment: *What* says that?

Comment: What does the register form server side look like? Is it possible you're doing something like `res.json({data: 'whatever'})` in the `POST /createNewUser` handler but not in the `POST /loginUser` handler?

Comment: I just updated the OP with it, all it does is put that data in a database. But when I was setting that up I could just console.log(req.body) like I'm trying now just fine, just to make sure it got on the server, so I'm not sure why that won't work for login.

Comment: Also @DaveNewton, it displays on the web page

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, thanks to @Rocky Sims for the help.

Basically, the register form doesn't exist on the login html page, which was throwing an error up about how that doesn't exist before it could even get to the login code. So I just had to make seperate register.js and login.js files, as the issue was due to them being in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your form method (post) in quotes ('')  like so `<form method='post' id="loginForm">`

Also the value for the name attribute for your password input should by in quotes. Like so `<input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name='password' required>`

Comment: Again, this didn't work for me, and also the register form already works. I've added quotes to everything, but also do note that the register form worked even before I added quotes, so I'm not sure if that could be some issue that I'm missing? And also is there a reason you're using single quotes for some things and double for others, aren't they read by the computer as the same?

Comment: The quotes don't matter. Test your login api with Postman to find if the problem is with the server side or client side. There might be a problem with how you are processing the login request.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you haven't told the server what to send back to the client when the POST /loginUser endpoint gets called. Try adding `res.sendStatus(200);` at the end of your POST /loginUser handler function (so right after `console.log(req.body.password);`).

Comment: That also didn't do it. I also went ahead and tried to just console.log the new username and new password with the '/createNewUser' handler and it worked, so I'm almost certain it's client side at this point.